# Is it possible to add variables with different names in a for loop in C?

Tags: c

I had something like this in mind but I don't know how to implement it.

As i'm a beginner (on the CS50 course), i don't really understand other answers I have came upon.

Thanks for your help!

```
for (int i = 1; i < 16; i++)
{
    int Ai= number % (10 * i);
}
```

Comment: It seems like you possibly want an *array*? What is the actual problem? What have you learned, so far, about scopes and variable life-time? Why do you need to define multiple variables inside the loop?

Comment: It isn't very clear what you want to do. If two variables have the *same* name, only the one in the most local scope is accessible. So you only *can* add variables with different names, unless they are elements of the same array.

Comment: Since C99 you can declare variables wherever you need them, before only at the beginning of a *block* – your example would be compliant to *both*, i.e. yes, it valid C. What you want to do with that snippet remains unclear, though. Just *any* snippet for illustration only?

Comment: C is a compiled language, so variable names are fixed at compile time.  If you want to access a value through an index, then you would use an array.  You should probably read a C tutorial, rather than just jumping in without knowing the most fundamental aspects of C, or of programming languages in general.  It will save you a vast amount of time in the long run.

Comment: Variable names are determined at compile time.  You cannot form them dynamically at runtime, such as by prefixing a value of variable `i` with the text `A`.

Comment: @Aconcagua You misunderstand the intent.  OP intends for `Ai` to be expanded into `A1`, `A2`, etc., creating a different variable name on each loop iteration.  So the answer is no, it can't be done in C, since variable names in C are fixed at compile time, not dynamically created at runtime.  Instead, in C an array would be the right solution.

Comment: ... so the loop should begin at `i=0` if you are going to work with `A[i]`. Your course should teach you about arrays.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the actual assignment you're supposed to solve. Copy-paste it as text into your question. Complete with all requirements and limitations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot do this, but you can create an array and append the values to the array. For example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int A[15];
for (int i = 1; i < 16; i += 1)
{
    //The reason for using i-1 as the index of the array is that i starts as 1, not 0 (array indices start at 0).
    A[i - 1] = number % (10 * i);
}

//The code below only prints the array.
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i += 1){
    printf("A%d: %d\n", i+1, arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Depending on the assignment, the array might not be needed. The code you show, for example, doesn't need an array.

Comment: Also, please don't try to mix styles and idioms, be consistent. It makes code much better. Like in one loop you have `i++` but in the other `i += 1`. Why the difference?

Comment: Sorry, I copied the code the OP had attached and forgot to change its style.

Comment: I just included the part that prints the contents of the array as proof of it working.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to write values to an array in a `for` loop. Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int arr[16];

    const int number = 200;

    //write numbers into array
    for ( int i = 0; i < 16; i++ )
    {
        arr[i] = number % ( 10 * (i+1) );
    }

    //print the array
    printf( "After writing, the array has the following content:\n" );
    for ( int i = 0; i < 16; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%02d: %d\n", i, arr[i] );
    }
}
```

Note that the indexes of arrays start at `0`, not at `1`.

This program has the following output:

```
After writing, the array has the following content:
00: 0
01: 0
02: 20
03: 0
04: 0
05: 20
06: 60
07: 40
08: 20
09: 0
10: 90
11: 80
12: 70
13: 60
14: 50
15: 40
```

You will learn about arrays in [week 2 of the CS50 course](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/weeks/2/).